# White frame appears in top of my navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I set the position:relative in #my-navbar a white frame appears in top of the navbar, but when I set position to absolute it doesn't appear. I need to get rid of that white frame while using position:relative.  My code:

```
#my-navbar{
background:url(images/bgfix.jpg) no-repeat; 
    height: 700px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o7otqnqv/

Comment: Facepalm didn't remember I added a 40px padding in my body, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it has `position: fixed`, giving it `position: relative` changes the way it functions.

Remove

```
body { 
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o7otqnqv/1))

I've added a background color to show you

Answer (score 2):

You have the entire body shifted down 40 px in your code. Setting the navbar to be absolutely positioned moved it to be in the top relative to the page, covering this body padding up.

```css
<style>
    body{
            padding-top: 40px;
        }
</style>
```